# Display only one book in Views

Tags: views, nodes

I have several books with several pages on them. 
I want to create a view to display page from a specific book. I'm pretty sure View can dop it but I don't find the way to.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter on nid or title. If you want to, you can add a contextual filter (top right) and let the filter work with the url.

Comment: But it only works if i load a book page url. I want to display it on my home page : each book has a block which lists all pages of each book

Comment: Use a regular filter (not a contextual one)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
It works with Content Title in filter :)

Comment: Please mark as answered if this helped you.